How to prevent multiple related records creation from a flow with a bulk insert?
I have a flow, that creates a related record to the record I'm creating. So, when I add a new Product to the Oppty, I create a record of the custom object ProductPool__c. The Product and the Product Pool have in common the Oppty ID and a Pool value, a custom picklist. I can have multiple Products on the Oppty, but only One Product Pool with the same Pool value. This PP record stores the total amount of all Oppty products with the same Pool value.
Now, to the flow. Upon adding a new Product with a Pool value firstly I do the Get Records, to look if there are PPs with the same Oppty ID, then I Loop through it and to each PP with the same PV with a Decision element, if there is a Pool already I do Get the amounts from all related Products to assign to that Pool, and then Assign to a created variable a 1. On the last element in that Loop go to the Decision, if the Variable is equal to 1, which means that there is a Pool, then the flow ends and that Pool vas updated, and the Default outcome is a creation for the new Pool with the Assigned Pool Value and Total amount.
Now here's the thing. When I create records one by one, everything works smoothly. But When I upload the Products with the same PV with Data Loader, I get multiple Pools with the same PV, as the system doesn't check if the Pools were created previously. They are created all at once and don’t check for each other. Can I prevent this from happening? I need to have only one Pool with the correspondent Pool Value in the end. I tried to edit the import batch size to 1 instead of 200 in Data Loader, but that is not an option in the end, I would need to load a lot of Products at once.
